# Redhat Apache 2.2.3 Not Loading

Tags: apache-2.2, redhat

I have Apache 2.2.3 installed on this server, and when I try loading its webpage, it does not load. I just get a loading sign that it is trying to connect but no connection has been made.

I check the conf file and it is listening on all ips on port 80. It also has a proper vhost file as well as has a simple text html file for the index display "Test".

**Some Additional Information:**

It neither works for the domain or the ip address or even localhost from the server. I did a wget of localhost and got nothing

```
[root@server conf]# netstat -tulpn | grep ':80'
tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      6256/httpd
```

My Apache conf: http://pastebin.com/MRDA8EkQ
Ip Tables Config: http://pastebin.com/nukXe5sD

Comment: Which you use to browse: domain or IP? Is there any firewall? Post the main and virtual host configuration file?

Comment: Could you append your question with the output of `netstat -tulpn | grep ':80'` and `iptables --list -n | grep '80'`

Comment: Here are the replies:

tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      6256/httpd

Comment: There was nothing for the ip tables grep. my apache config is here: http://pastebin.com/MRDA8EkQ

Comment: it neither works for the domain or the ip address or even localhost from the server. i did a wget of localhost and got nothing

Comment: I also posted the IP tables config

Comment: do you have anythin special in apache logs ? pelae also try to use tcpdump and check if you really get connection to port 80 (just in case)

Comment: What is the output of `getenforce` and `ps -ZC httpd`?

Comment: Does it start working if you `/etc/init.d/iptables stop` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your firewall needs to allow access on port 80 try

```
/sbin/iptables -I RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

and see if that works. If it does then save your firewall configuration with

```
/sbin/service iptables save
```

Answer (score 0):

1) What is the output of your error_log after you restart Apache ?

2) Can you do telnet localhost 80 ? If so, try to do  `GET /<enter>`

3) It is surprising that iptables block requests from localhost as well